# sudden surge of thousands in reputation

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

on my account page, a link said I'm in the top 2% this week for reputation.  I looked at the list and it shows me having a change of +49287 in reputation.  Yet I'm back to my humble 358.  Just curious about what happened.

Comment: That's *rank*, not reputation.

Comment: heh, I guess I better downvote myself.  you answered the question though, so if you make an actual answer I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That +49287 you see is your increase in *rank* for the category that you're looking at. Your increase in *reputation* is a different number.